# Pydantic validation error None is not allowed

Tags: python, flask, pydantic

Having the following Pydantic basemodels that will adapt the artist data fetched through the Spotify API

```
class Followers(BaseModel):
    href: Optional[str]
    total: int

class Images(BaseModel):
    height: int
    url: str
    width: int


class Artist(BaseModel):
    external_urls: Dict[str, str]
    followers: Optional[Followers]
    genres: List[str]
    href: str
    spotify_artist_id: str = Field(alias="id")
    images: List[Images]
    name: str
    popularity: int
    artist_type: str = Field(alias='type')
    uri: str
```

This will be the artist I am using to send the data:

```
artist = 
external_urls={'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB'}
followers=Followers(href=None, total=24927695) 
genres=['hard rock', 'metal', 'old school thrash', 'rock', 'thrash metal']
href='https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB' 
spotify_artist_id='2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB' 
images=[Images(height=640, url='https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb69ca98dd3083f1082d740e44', width=640), Images(height=320, url='https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000517469ca98dd3083f1082d740e44', width=320), 
Images(height=160, url='https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f17869ca98dd3083f1082d740e44', width=160)] 
name='Metallica' 
popularity=82 
artist_type='artist' 
uri='spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB'
```

This is the Flask Endpoint

```
@app.route("/test_artist", methods=['PUT'])
@validate()
   def test_artist(artist: Artist):
        print("hello world")
```

And this is how I am sending the artist

```
    # When updating with a put
    result = client.put("/test_artist",
                        json=artist.dict())
```

Even when I modify the href from BaseModel followers I am getting an
b'{"validation_error":{"path_params":[{"loc":["artist"],"msg":"none is not an allowed value","type":"type_error.none.not_allowed"}]}}\n'

Why? is it followers not Optional? and followers.href too?

I am really stucked

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. The code as presented doesn't run -- for example, your `artist` example isn't valid Python. It would be helpful if we could copy and paste your examples to reproduce the behavior you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that ultimately this will turn out to be confusion about how field aliases work, but there are a couple of issues here.

## Field aliases

It looks like you're trying to create an `Artist` object using the `spotify_artist_id` and `artist_type` attributes, but because you've assigned aliases to these fields...

```
class Artist(BaseModel):
    spotify_artist_id: str = Field(alias="id")
    artist_type: str = Field(alias="type")
```

...you must either (a) set the fields using the alias name, or (b) configure the models to except the original name (or (c) drop the field aliases). So for example this successfully creates an Artist object:

```
artist = Artist(
    external_urls={"spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB"},
    followers=Followers(href=None, total=24927695),
    genres=["hard rock", "metal", "old school thrash", "rock", "thrash metal"],
    href="https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    id="2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    images=[
        Images(
            height=640,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb69ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=640,
        ),
        Images(
            height=320,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000517469ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=320,
        ),
        Images(
            height=160,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f17869ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=160,
        ),
    ],
    name="Metallica",
    popularity=82,
    type="artist",
    uri="spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
)
```

And then you would access the fields using the "long" name:

```
>>> artist.spotify_artist_id
'2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB'
>>> artist.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Artist' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Alternatley, you can set the `allow_population_by_field_name` option on your `Artist` class:

```
class Artist(BaseModel):
    external_urls: Dict[str, str]
    followers: Optional[Followers]
    genres: List[str]
    href: str
    spotify_artist_id: str = Field(alias="id")
    images: List[Images]
    name: str
    popularity: int
    artist_type: str = Field(alias="type")
    uri: str

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
```

This would allow the (corrected) version of your original example to run successfully:

```
artist = Artist(
    external_urls={"spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB"},
    followers=Followers(href=None, total=24927695),
    genres=["hard rock", "metal", "old school thrash", "rock", "thrash metal"],
    href="https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    spotify_artist_id="2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
    images=[
        Images(
            height=640,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5eb69ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=640,
        ),
        Images(
            height=320,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000517469ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=320,
        ),
        Images(
            height=160,
            url="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000f17869ca98dd3083f1082d740e44",
            width=160,
        ),
    ],
    name="Metallica",
    popularity=82,
    artist_type="artist",
    uri="spotify:artist:2ye2Wgw4gimLv2eAKyk1NB",
)
```

With this option enabled you can instantiate the class using *either* the original field name or the alias.

## Flask syntax

You've defined your Flask application like this:

```
@app.route("/test_artist", methods=['PUT'])
def test_artist(artist: Artist):
       print("hello world")
```

...but that looks like you've been reading the [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) documentation. In Flask, we would typically write something like this (this method receives an Artist in JSON format in the request body and returns the same thing):

```
@app.route("/test_artist", methods=['PUT'])
def test_artist():
    new_artist = Artist.parse_obj(request.get_json())
    return new_artist.dict()
```

See e.g. [this article](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-get-and-parse-http-post-body-in-flask-json-and-form-data/) for additional examples.

---

Unrelated to your question, but if you're using a recent (3.10+) version of Python you can replace the use of `typing.Any`, `typing.Dict`, and `typing.List` with native types; e.g:

```
class Artist(BaseModel):
    external_urls: dict[str, str]
    followers: Followers|None
    genres: list[str]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's good to see that it's working and that someone also took the chance to explain things. Gentleman, you make this world a little bit better for the juniors